# Node.js: Serve JSON document

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

```
user = https.request options, (res) ->
        data = ''
        res.on 'data', (chunk) ->
            data += chunk
            return
        res.on 'end', ->
            if res.statusCode is 200
                console.log "oops?"
                usr = JSON.parse(data)
                console.log usr.status

            else
                console.log "oops2?"
                new Error "Response status code: " + res.statusCode
            return
        return
    user.end()
    res.write usr
```

I want to return the JSON document but I am unable to.

Thanks

Comment: What do u mean by return? Can you be more specific? Thanks

Comment: @alFReD NSH - print the JSON document in the browser when the request comes from there

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I guess you should attempt some thing basic in plain javascript first before jumping to cs!

Solution, Here res.write usr should be right after  usr = JSON.parse(data) !! Also, you should set  res.contentType('application/json');

http://expressjs.com/ is recommended if you are really going to grow your code beyond this.